# sql scalar function returns invalid quarter

Tags: sql, date, user-defined-functions

I am sure that I am overlooking some simple thing, I admit that I am still learning various aspects of SQL and the Datepart function is one..

I am inputting a date and returning an invalid quarter, here is the code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION Dbo.FN_Get_Quarter (
  -- the parameters for the function here
  @date                  varchar(10)
) RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN

  RETURN datepart(qq,@date)

END
```

Here is the test I am using and the returned value...

```
select dbo.FN_GET_QUARTER('07-14-2010')
```

...returns 1

Answer (score 1):

datepart returns an int, but you've declared your function return type as bit

Answer (score 0):

Returning a BIT means the value can only be 0 or 1.  So you have to change your data type to INT to get the actual value being returned:

```
ALTER FUNCTION Dbo.FN_Get_Quarter (
  @date                  varchar(10)
) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

  RETURN datepart(qq,@date)

END
```

Comment: Oh so simple! I feel a bit foolish for overlooking that, thanks!